# Why does building a library using Vue CLI cause an error?

Tags: vue.js, build

Immediately after creating the application (without making any changes), I start building the library, according to the official documentation: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app

```
npm run build --target lib --name myLib 'src/components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

As a result, I get the following error: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\domains\vue-hello-world\lib' in 'C:\domains\vue-hello-world'

[image]

I also tried to build the library with this command:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib 'src/components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

And got another error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `App.vue` as your entry file? So you could just run `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib`

Comment: @TroyKessler Yes, tried this, but got the same errors

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib`
`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib 'src/App.vue'`
`npm run build --target lib --name myLib`
`npm run build --target lib --name myLib 'src/App.vue'`

Comment: @NikitaDrozhzhin did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the exact same issue and can't seem to find anything that solves it.